# Django - How to allow inheritance of swappable model?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I am using [swappable](https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models) to make a reusable app (named `Meat`) that provides models that Developers can swap for their own.  That model is a super class of other models.

```py
from django.db.models import Model, CharField
from swapper import swappable_setting

class AbstractMeat(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    name = CharField(max_length=16)

class Meat(AbstractMeat):
    class Meta:
        swappable = swappable_setting("cyber", "Meat")

class Pork(Meat):
    pass

class Fish(Meat):
    pass
```

To test this, i created the `real` app and set `MEAT_MEAT_MODEL`.

```py
# settings.py
MEAT_MEAT_MODEL = "real.RealMeat"

# real/models.py
from django.forms import IntegerField
from cyber.models import AbstractMeat

class RealMeat(AbstractMeat):
    price = IntegerField()
```

Running `runserver` i get this error:

```
meat.Fish.meat_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'meat.Meat', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.MEAT_MEAT_MODEL'.
meat.Pork.meat_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'meat.Meat', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.MEAT_MEAT_MODEL'.
```

This error arises on Django 1.9 to 1.11, but for my purpose only 1.11 is critical.

I tried overriding the `meat_ptr` as instructed in [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) like so:

```py
from swapper import get_model_name
from django.db.models import OneToOneField, CASCADE

class Pork(Meat):
    meat_ptr = OneToOneField(
        get_model_name("meat", "Meat"), CASCADE,
        parent_link=True)
```

But it gives me this error on 1.11 and 1.10 (but not 1.9):

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Auto-generated field 'meat_ptr' in class 'Pork' for parent_link to base class 'Meat' clashes with declared field of the same name.
```

In conclusion, how do i make this happen?

Comment: Do you managed to do what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override that field, it looks like you'll have to call it something other than meat_ptr. The autogenerated field is called that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance